# How to show a set of vectors are a basic for a given plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

To determine if a set, $B$, of the vectors, $\bf u$, and $\bf v$ for a basis for the plane, $W$.

let $\mathbf {u}=(1,2,-1)$, and $\mathbf{v}=(1,1,1)$, $W =-3x+2y+z=0$.

I was able to determine the two vectors, $\mathbf{w}[1]$, and $\mathbf{w}[2]$,  from $s$ and $t$ that for a basis for that plane....and that $\bf u$ and $\bf v$ are linearly independent of each other.  how do I determine the relationship between that set of vectors, $B$, and the plane $W$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to verify two things:(a) $u,v$ are in the plane $W,$ (b) $u, v$ are linearly independent.

you can verify that $\pmatrix{1\\2\\-1}$ is in $W = -3x + 2y + z = -3(1) + 2(2) + (-1) = 0$ i will let you verify that $v \in W.$

$u, v$ are linearly independent because $u$ is not a multiple of $v.$

Comment: by checking that that they are equal to zero when you plug the vectors components into the plan - you are checking to see if there is no difference or displacement between any of the components and the plane?

Comment: you can think of the plane containing all vectors $\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}$ that are orthogonal to the vector $\pmatrix{-3\\2\\1}.$

Answer (score 0):

Here $W$ is a two-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ (check this!). It follows
that $\{\mathbf u,\mathbf v\}$ form a basis for  $W$ if and only    if $\mathbf u$
and $\mathbf v$    are linearly independent and belong to $W$. In this case it is
quite easy to check that $\mathbf u\in W$ and $\mathbf v\in W$. Can you
determine if $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are linearly independent?

Comment: **u** and **v** will be linearly independent if they are not scalar multiples of each other. Which at a glance they are not. By inspection, I cannot see any scalar _k_ that would let **u**=**v**.

Comment: That's right. This proves that $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ form a basis for $W$.